# Apex objects in a Set

Tags: apex, set

The documentation on the Apex class `Set` is quite straightforward, but it omits to mention what happens if you create a set of some Apex class:

```
Set<MyApexClass> mySet = new Set<MyApexClass>();
```

Since sets cannot contain duplicate entries, in the case of MyApexClass, how can it tell whether two instances are to be treated as equal?

In Java, one would simply over-ride the `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()` methods, and the Set implementation would use use those methods to check for duplicates. Is there a similar mechanism in Apex?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my own question - yes there is a similar mechanism. Here it is:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm

Quite why this is not mentioned on the Set documentation I don't know.